# How to use use-package's :bind to bind key-chords

Tags: use-package, key-chord-mode

```
(use-package whatever :bind (("C-a b" . aabb)))
```

can be used to replace

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a b" 'aabb))
```

Can `use-package`'s `:bind` be used to replace

```
(key-chord-define-global "ab" 'aabb)
```

?

Comment: Does https://github.com/waymondo/use-package-chords help you?

Comment: @MarcoWahl Yes, that does the trick very nicely. The mind boggles as to how my searches failed to find it: I guess because I was implicitly expecting to use `:bind`, while this uses a different keyword.